# SQL to find discount on item level

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I use MySQL
I have an **Order** table:

```
Order  |  Items | Discount

+++++++++++++++++

A      |   04 | 10
```

and an **Items** table:

```
Order | Items | Discount

+++++++++++++++++++

A  | 02 |

A  | 01 |  

A  | 01 |
```

I need to find the discount per item level.
which would be

```
2/4 * 10  = 5 for 1st item
1/4 * 10  = 2.5 for 2nd item
1/4 * 10  = 2.5 for 3rd item
```

Need to compute and save discounts on the items table.

Comment: Why does your Order table look exactly like your Items table? Is that intentional?

Comment: no, its not intentional. i derive these columns from the Orders and Items table and wanted to perform this logic. Orders.order =Items.order are related.

Comment: So your result set consists of an Order column, Items column, and Discount column?

Comment: Yes and would like to compute the Discount for each items based on the order discount

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so based on your comments, you're looking for something like:

```
UPDATE Items SET Discount = (SELECT ((I.Items/O.Items) * O.Discount) FROM
    Order O JOIN Items I ON O.Order = Items.Order WHERE O.Order = 'A')
    WHERE Items.Order = 'A';
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. It works for product 'A'. But when i have multiple products i need to again run multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of an attribute (or a methodology) for defining what the ordering is, it is impossible to apply a transformation which uses the order as a parameter and get consistent results.